# Why does the Prime Directive not apply to Rubicun III?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, prime-directive

In a first season episode of *Star Trek: The Next Generation* the Enterprise visits a planet named Rubicun III where ([according to Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rubicun_III)) the Edo live.

It is often mentioned in Star Trek that the Prime Directive requires that pre-Warp civilisations be ignored until they discover Warp mechanics. But this planet and civilisation appears to be exempt from that status. Why?

Comment: Was there any indication that the Edo were pre-warp? That's not how I (vaguely) remember it.

Comment: The Edo mention how the Enterprise officers are more advanced than them and seemingly have never been off-planet before since the Edo woman brought to the Enterprise is very much in awe and then very fearful when she sees her "god" out the window. Given the "god"'s protective nature it also seems unlikely he'd let them develop warp technology.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Criticism about the effective application of the Prime Directive in Star Trek stories goes back to The Original Series and every iteration has a few episodes that gloss over, overlook, forget, or simply ignore the Prime Directive for the sake of story continuity.

In the case of the Next Generation episode Justice, in which the Edo appear Wikipedia indicates:

> **In contrast, the Next Generation episode "Justice" did not explicitly
> explain whether the Edo people were pre-warp or were aware of offworld
> space travelers prior to the Enterprise's visit. If the case is the
> former, then when Wesley Crusher is sentenced to death, the violation
> of the Prime Directive had already occurred and the issue of rescuing
> him, while politically exacerbating matters, might not have been a
> violation of the Directive.**

Emphasis is mine.

Violations of the [Prime Directive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Directive) are numerous and recounted in the Prime Directive entry in Wikipedia:

> One criticism regarding the Prime Directive is that it is
> inconsistently applied, depending on a planet's strategic importance
> or the circumstances in which a starship crew finds itself. **For
> example, as part of the Federation's then-ongoing hostilities with the
> Klingons, Captain Kirk was ordered to make contact with the seemingly
> pre-industrial Organians in "Errand of Mercy."** In addition, Kirk
> directly interfered with the laws or customs of alien worlds in
> "Friday's Child," "For the World Is Hollow and I Have Touched the
> Sky," "The Cloud Minders," "The Apple," "The Return of the Archons,"
> and "A Taste of Armageddon," in order to achieve a Federation
> objective, to save the lives of his crew, or both.
>
> Compounding matters is that in the TOS episode "The Omega Glory," Kirk
> states, "A star captain's most solemn oath is that he will give his
> life, even his entire crew, rather than violate the Prime Directive,"
> and yet he seemingly violates the Prime Directive as "the only way to
> save my ship" in "A Taste of Armageddon" and no explanation for the
> Federation Ambassador trying to mediate between Eminiar VII and
> Vendikar (neither of which are Federation members) regardless of their
> wishes on the matter is given.
>
> In "The Return of the Archons" and "The Apple" reference to the "Prime
> Directive of non-interference" is made by Spock. In "The Return Of The
> Archons," Kirk says the Prime Directive refers to "a living, growing
> culture" to justify interfering with what he sees as the
> non-development of the computer-controlled culture, asking pointedly
> in reference to it, by contrasting it with living, growing cultures,
> "Do you think this one is?" In the "The Apple" Spock points out that
> Starfleet Command may not agree with his choice to interfere with the
> computer controlled culture to which Kirk replies "I'll take my
> chances."
>
> There are also episodes in which the Prime Directive should have been
> mentioned, but wasn't. In "The Paradise Syndrome"," the Enterprise
> attempts to save a pre-industrial planet by moving an asteroid that
> was on a collision course with it; when McCoy asks Kirk if he should
> warn the people, Kirk and Spock only point out the people would not
> understand the warning, and neither makes any reference to the Prime
> Directive. In "The Cloud Minders Kirk interferes with the culture of
> Ardana to obtain zenite the only cure for a biological plague ravaging
> Merak.
>
> Admiral Matthew Dougherty's reasons for violation of the Prime
> Directive in Star Trek: Insurrection in Picard's time echoes the
> reasons Kirk gives McCoy in "Private Little War" but Picard considers
> them invalid. In "Homeward," Nikolai Rozhenko (Paul Sorvino) uses
> holodeck technology to save the Boraalan and enforce what he believes
> is the spirit of the Prime Directive even though Picard has already
> said such actions violate what it actually states. In "Pen Pals,"
> Captain Picard rectifies contact with an inhabitant of a pre-warp
> planet by ordering her memory erased. When contamination became too
> serious to be fixed by memory erasures, Captain Picard decided to make
> direct contact with a civilization's leaders in "Who Watches the
> Watchers" and "First Contact," although the latter episode involved a
> planet on the verge of achieving warp flight, and therefore eligible
> for First Contact. Finally, in "Natural Law," the Voyager crew took
> measures to ensure the protected isolation of a primitive people, even
> from a more advanced civilization who share the same planet.

Answer (score 11):

The Prime Directive rules against ***revealing the presence of extra-terrestrials*** only seems to apply to pre-*contact* civilisations, not pre-*warp* civilisations. On numerous occasions ([TNG: Code of Honor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Code_of_Honor_(episode)), [TNG: Justice](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Justice_%28episode%29), [TNG: Pen Pals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pen_Pals_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29), [TOS: Errand of Mercy](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Errand_of_Mercy_(episode)), etc) it's made abundantly clear that as long as a planet is already aware of the *existence* of extra-terrestrials, it's OK for Starfleet to have diplomatic relations with them. At that point, the Prime Directive appears to switch to one of ***preventing undue influence.***

In this particular case, Rubicun is described (by Data) as being part of a *star-cluster* of ...

> ...three thousand four other planets

Many of which are evidently suitable for both life and colonisation.

Despite their simplistic pre-warp lifestyle, it seems at least reasonable to assume that in such a densely packed environment, Edo scientists would have been aware of other civilisations through simple observation.

Comment: I disagree with at least two of your examples.  In Code of Honor, according to the summary you linked to, it was a warp-capable civilization (they had transporters) and in Pen Pals, it was made clear that Data's contact with Sarjenka was in fact in violation of the Prime Directive.  Errand of Mercy makes a better argument, but it may have been seen as a justifiable violation in the context of the Klingon/Federation conflict.  (And of course Justice is the episode the OP was asking about in the first place.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Tranporters don't equal warp tech.

Comment: In *Enterprise*, Earth developed transporters almost a generation later than warp drive.  That doesn't necessarily make it a hard-and-fast rule, but unless there are canonical counterexamples it seems like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - In light of the Ligonian's lack of advanced technology, it would seem more likely that the transporters were a gift rather than something they developed themselves.

Comment: According to the article, they also had an orbital control station.  Again, that doesn't prove they were warp-capable, but it does demonstrate that they weren't as primitive as you might assume from their culture.  (Consider how Vulcan was portrayed in *Amok Time*!)  In the absence of further evidence, my interpretation is that the Ligonians had warp-level technology, but simply chose not to incorporate it into their society other than as necessary to deal with outsiders.  However, I acknowledge that your interpretation is equally plausible.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - In the total absence of any evidence that they have it, it's more likely that they don't have it.

Comment: OK, I had to watch most of the episode to find anything, but it seems clear that the Edo at least did not have spaceflight technology.  It does seem likely that they have been contacted before, since they took the presence of the landing crew so calmly.  So interpreting the Prime Directive as a rule against interfering with pre-contact civilizations makes sense - though I believe there are some episodes that explicitly contradict it, e.g., *False Profits*, but then ST has never been particularly consistent. :-)

Comment: In the *Star Trek: Discovery* episode "The Sound of Thunder" has mention that contact with the Kelpians won't violate the Prime Directive even though they're technologically very primitive. The reason given is that the Kelpians are well aware of and exposed to the advanced technology and spaceflight capability of the Ba'ul, and the Ba'ul know about other space-faring civilizations, thus there's a reasonable chance the Kelpians could be aware there are others out there as well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to depend on what type of contact another civilization has had, not how advanced they are-the Federation has clearly had contact with pre-warp civilizations that already knew about "aliens."

It's interesting to note that violations by Picard and his crew are mostly accidental, and Picard does everything he can to keep things the way they are on the planet involved until they are deemed ready for contact. Kirk, on the other hand, seems more interested in deliberately changing a planet's culture ahead of time if he thinks it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it was a first season episode.  It wasn't until the third season that they decided the Prime Directive was a non-contact directive.  There were several open contacts with pre-warp drive cultures in the first season like Angel One and Code of Honor. It was only with Who Watches The Watchers that the rules had changed and suddenly the Federation was only observing them in secrecy.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up this bold statement?

Comment: That sounds like the sort of thing that should be in your answer....

Answer (score 0):

In TOS, there appears to be an exception in place for planets in the "disputed territory" with the Klingons. This makes sense since the Klingons clearly have no such law and contamination seems inevitable.  Note how "A Private Little War" referred to Kirk's previous recommendation, not the Prime Directive.

There's nothing in TOS to indicate the PD includes saving worlds from natural disasters and "The Paradise Syndrome" seems to make the opposite argument.  That application of the PD started with "Pen Pals".

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do either of those cases (disputed planet or natural disaster) apply to Rubicon III?  If not, how does this answer the question?